# how can i upgrade bootstrap framework without changing html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a requirement like,i need to migrate from bootstrap2 to bootstrap3,but there should not be any change in html side.is it possible,if so how can we acheive it.

Comment: Your question is too general. You must have a specific problem that you encountered while attempting your migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change the code, try this before: http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/

Answer (score 0):

It's *not* possible to migrate from Bootstrap 2 to 3 without [many changes](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide) to the HTML markup. There are a lot of changes in CSS class names between the 2 versions. You can use a tool like this to help with code migration: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/